# How can I get a content of a specific CMD Window in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, console

I ran a job that generated a new CMD Window, in the CMD window there is all the data I want to copy into a file.

I am able to find the relevant process by below command:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -eq "xxx Command Prompt"}
```

However, I would like to get (copy to a file) the content of what is written inside the CMD (which I found its process).

Comment: I don't think that'll work. What are you running in the CMD window, and how is that started? It'd probably be better to redirect the output of whatever command you're running to a file.

Comment: Yes I know but in this scenario I can not 
I need to extract the content from the CMD window